# Header disappears to show ribbon from top of page when web part clicked

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When I click on a web part on the SharePoint page the header disappears and the ribbon then displays. How can I prevent the header from being replaced by the ribbon? It is ok that the ribbon is displayed when a web part is clicked however I would like the header to also remain on the page permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, this is an intended behavior of SharePoint 2010 though your guess is as good as mine as to why.  Basically, you will need to create a custom master page and move things around a bit to prevent this from happening.  Heather Solomon has an excellent post that covers [how to fix this problem](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/04/26/boil-down-to-basics-sharepoint-2010-ribbon/).